# Get Latest Updated Record from Nested Collection in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I am working on Microsoft Azure-based application where I am using Azure Cosmos Trigger to get the change feed from the collections. I have nested records in a single collection. From UI, users can modify the nested records. Now, my requirement is to get the information about the record which was modified from the UI but cosmos trigger is returning all the data from the collection whereas I want to get a single modified record from the nested collection. Any suggestions how this can be done, if feasible? Returning whole collection will take too much time for UI to load.

Comment: I think it is by design. If something has changed in the document then the function is triggered. Maybe you should create another collection rather than having subdocuments ??

Answer (score 1):

I published a [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-hl7-fhir-logic-apps) to the Cosmos DB documentation. This uses the `CreateDocumentChangeFeedQuery`

```
var results = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<dynamic>().ConfigureAwait(false);
if (results.Count > 0)                                    
    docs.AddRange(results.Where(doc => doc.resourceType == resourceType));
```

**Allows you to filter**